# Can "Regret" Be Used With a Condition?

Tags: semantics

Can the word "regret" be used with a condition? For example, could I say, "I regret my sadness"? This a just a quick example.

I understand that the word is most often used to describe someone's feeling toward a past action.

Comment: Of course, I regret your nastiness, I regret your friendliness [towards that idiot], I regret her maladroitness. forthrightness, etc. All those are just nouns, really.

Comment: I regret my drunkenness (if not now then later).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Syntactically it's fine, but pragmatically it's a rather strange thing to say: it sounds like "I regret causing myself sadness". If the context is a situation where you were supposed to feel happy for someone but you felt sad instead (or as well), then I'd suggest "I regret feeling sad", or "I regret that I felt sad".

Comment: I agree; it does sound unusual. I probably won't use the construction. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

> We regret the confusion we caused some readers with our stories on metabolism and food.

However, this might apply only to what [oxforddictionairies.com](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/regret) describes as 'polite formulas'

> Used in polite formulas to express apology for or sadness over something undesirable.

I am not a native speaker. Someone who is might add his two cents regarding less formal contexts.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I suspect that a "polite formula" is nothing more than formal speech, since I can't find many answers online concerning what it is.

Answer (score 1):

The usual pattern with the verb regret is

> 'I regret (doing something that ended up being bad)'

or

> 'I regret X-ing (something that I was responsible for...'.

To say 'I regret (any noun phrase at all), like 'I regret the house that was built by the old man' doesn't make much sense.

> I regret my being sad for so many years

is the way to say your given sentence.